# How to start asp.net core server on linux and keep it running

Tags: asp.net, linux, nginx, ssh, asp.net-core

I have created basic ASP.Net Core server on Azure Ubuntu VM. I have exposed the server to a port 80 using nginx.
I am conecting to the VM via ssh.
And starting the server with "dotnet run" command.
That works fine.

However, every time I close the ssh connection, the server is stopping as well.
Is there a way to start and keep running the asp.net core server on Linux without having an active ssh connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what happens is:

1. You login with ssh
2. you startup an application under your user (`dotnet run`)
3. Close your ssh => logging out user, which means application is closed.

You need to start a service outside of your user. Here is some information:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

Otherwise i'd advice you to ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The instructions on that blog didn't help... Maybe I did something wrong (editing the file in /etc/init.d folder). Basically when I started the service nothing happened.

However I have asked a question on askubuntu.com and it was redirected to the following question that have actually helped:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session